# Moving <hr> vertically

Tags: html, css

[image]I'm trying to put a line in html. I found the 'hr' tag but it looks like it has a default position in html. Is there a way to move it (more or less like word) nearest the text? Here is my code. The hr tag is in a div

```
 <h5 style="color: black; text-align: left; margin-top: 1px; margin-left: 5px">SONG</h5>
 <h5 style="color: black; text-align: left; margin-top: -46px; margin-left:       280px">ARTIST</h5>
 <h5 style="color: black; text-align: left; margin-top: -46px; margin-left: 555px">ALBUM</h5>
 <h5 style="color: black; text-align: right; margin-top: -46px;">TIME</h5>
 <hr>
 <p color="black" face="verdana" style="margin-top: -20px; margin-left: 5px; font-size:15px">Live like theres no tomorrow</p>
 <hr>
```

Basically I want to use the live to divide the various songs. Just to be sure I'm not using JavaScript and I'm at the base of HTML.

Comment: Why not use the `border` (`border-top`, `border-bottom`) property?

Comment: Not sure about where and how much you want to move it? If you update your question with a little more description I can send you an example.

Comment: I'll sent an image of what I want to do

Comment: looking at my update knittl are they border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just want an html table. I made you an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/b2boteLj/3/

html:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
      <th><h5>SONG</h5></th>
      <th><h5>ARTIST</h5></th>
      <th><h5>ALBUM</h5></th>
      <th><h5>TIME</h5></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Live like theres no tomorrow</td>
      <td>some artist</td>
      <td>some album</td>
      <td>some time</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
table, th, td {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: left;
}
th {
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
}
td {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
th,td {
     padding: 5px;
}
```

This structure can also be used (with some added css) for striped alternating rows etc. Also, please note that `<td>` is a table cell and `<th>` is a table header cell - this can be helpful if you want to apply different css parameters to the titles of columns. For more information on html tables and styling them refer here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

If it's not what you want let me know and I'll make another example.

Comment: Uao!! Amazing. Yes basically is the same structure of the latex (more or less). I don't have anything to say. I have no words. Thanks Drew. Sorry if I was late and I answer you just now

Comment: I'm sorry, do you know how can I reduce the block of Song, Artist... Basically I want to reduce the height but I did not find anything. I find height but after some point I can't reduce it more

Comment: It's because you are using `<h5>` tags which are for titles - they have a built in default padding and margin. Just add css `margin: 0` and `padding: 0` to them. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/b2boteLj/4/

Answer (score 0):

Using `hr` nowadays is generally considered a somewhat bad practice, because it's only used as a visual element without any contextual meaning. We use `border` instead.

P.S.: putting inline styles in your code is a bad practice as well. Maybe you've did it just for the sake of the example, but in real life prefer external css files whenever possible.

Comment: yeah I can understand your answer but that's the fact. I have to do just a visual interface (of a Music Player)

Comment: Looking at my update, are they border? If yes, where should I have to insert them?

Comment: @user28011994, your example looks like a simple `table`, which has borders by default for individual cells... You can specify rules for applying border based on your needs. If you want to know how to style a table, I bet you will find plenty of resources online. It's quite a broad topic to explain in whole here.